# Loading properties of jar A from jar B in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I have a project in Tomcat with a lot of jars. I have a properties A inside A.jar and I want to load the A.properties from B.jar. All of them are in the same WEB-INF.

Why can't I load the properties? If I copy A.properties to the resources of project B, it works.

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream file;
        InputStream is =
                getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/com/projectA/others/A.properties");

        try {
            prop.load(is);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have access to servletcontext instance? Try using ctx.getResourceAsStream("some/package/file.properties") method.

Comment: I fixed it,, it was because I was using absolute path.